# Nvidia GTX 960 In Proliant DL320 G6. Will it work?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, pci-express, hp-proliant

I am considering buying a Nvidia GTX 960 to put in a Proliant DL320 G6. **The Proliant has:**

- Dual Redundant 400W power supplies
- 2x Full sized PCIe 2.0 x16 slots

From What I have read Nivida says

> 120W Graphics Card Power
>
> 400W Recommended System Power

With current Hardware ILO shows I don't go over 200W... Thus I should Have 80W to spare, Right?
I also know this would fill one PCIe Slot, but fill both PCIe Spaces.
I am also aware that this card is meant for PCIe 3.0, Thus even with PCIe backwards compatibility I wouldn't get the full bandwidth.

---

It looks good to me... But to anyone with experience,

## WILL IT WORK?

Comment: Also to add this GPU would be used for DATA computations

Comment: Wouldn't you be connecting the GPU to just one of those power supplies though?

Comment: Unfortunately the power supplies are hot-swappable so the cables don't actually come off the power supply they come off of the unit that the power supplies slide into the power supply where the power comes out actually looks kind of like a PCI card its PCB board and copper the main problem with these though is that they are redundant so you can't use both of them only one of the time from what I know

Comment: I don't think a redundant power supplies double your maximum system wattage though.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying :)

Comment: In any event you have more then enough power for the card.

Comment: Good, that's what I had figured. In theory if I could figure out power connectors, would it work?

Comment: Dual redundant Psu's only means if one fails the other takes over, so you only have 400w at any given time and the Nvidia card requires a 6 pin supplementary power cable connected to it, which you don't have on the psu's,, no it wont work.

Comment: @Moab I know I dont have the connector... Worst case scenario, Ill bring the power in another way... The bigger question is Will it fit and communicate properly regardless of power ;)